# Flask Python Data Interchange with background tasks

Tags: python, database, background, flask, task

I am attempting to make a web enabled security system using a raspberry pi Linux computer.

So far I have a flask application that allows viewing zone status and arming/disarming of the system.

I also have two other python programs, one that polls hardware at 1Hz and writes the "ZONES" binary status bits to the SQLite database (Secured or not Secured).  The other program pulls the ZONES data from the DB and watches for zone changes while armed, and plays a siren sound, etc.

The system mostly works, but I don't feel like writing data to the DB every 1 second on an SD Card is ideal, and there has to be a better way.

I'm very new to python and Flask.  When the flask application is running on a 'production' web server, is there a proper way to get a flask app to run event driven code without user interaction via the web?  Am I using the database correctly as a proper abstraction layer for my data?

Can Flask-Script help me solve this problem?

Comment: is there any reason you're not using a single program to poll the hardware and handle the alarms?

Comment: Well, I initially split the 'control' and the 'interface' (flask app) into two apps.  Once I finished populating the DB with the hardware, I split to a third app to monitor it.  I guess merging those back would save a lot of DB read/write since I would only need to update the DB on zone change.  I just wanted to keep them separate in case someone wanted to use non-raspberry pi hardware to populate the ZONES table, for instance an arduino, or some wireless zones, X10, etc.  The 'hardware' program could easily be exchanged for a different hardware source and the alarm code would be untouched.

Comment: You could read the database in the populating process and only write if there actually is a change. Do you need the data to be persistent? A redis server might be a solution, you can then use its pub-sub for notifications, without polling.

Comment: I've been thinking about why I split the two 'non-flask' programs in the first place, and I think the cost is far outweighing the benefits.  If I simply import the hardware read into the 'alarmlogic' program, and populate a ZONES dictionary in program memory instead, I can avoid a cyclical database writes.  That way, I can initiate a write only when a zone changes state so that the flask app can find out about it.  I would think the DB engine would avoid disk IO unless the data changed, but I'm not sure it does.  Thanks for the comments, I think merging those programs should work for me.

Comment: fyi, you can find my almost-working app here: https://github.com/evanmj/calzone/wiki